# How do I manage to stay alive in Underworld?

Tags: terraria

As already said in the title, I always get burned in lava, or the enemies kill me in the Underworld.

I'm Pre-Hardmode, I have max health, anicent shadow armor (about 25 defense), and I'm fighting with ice blade and bee keeper right now. I easily managed to kill The Eye of Cthulhu, Eater of Worlds, King Slime, Queen Bee and Skeletron.

However every time I want to explore Underworld, I die after less then five minutes. What am I doing wrong? Any tips to stay alive? 
I want to mine hellstone there to get the Fiery Greatsword, as it is the last sword I need to craft Nights Edge.

Comment: I didn't read all. Getting burned in lava caught my attention. Do you know where you want to be, or go? I don't, but I am.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is upon going to the underworld, I immediately go mining for hellstone. I quickly hide underground and look out for fire imps (advantage of pickaxe as it breaks burning spheres).

---

I mine hellstone by mining it through a wall and collecting it through a wall (because of the lava). When I get Hellstone armor (and perhaps fiery greatsword), I find it easier to survive

---

As my exit, I use a piece of rope as you can ascend fairly quickly, from which I never go too far away. You can also build a starting platform (which you might later use for WoF). Hermes boots and Rocket boots are very handy in the situation. You should also get the Cobalt (or Obsidian) shield, because it prevents enemies from pushing you into the lava.